# Using props to toggle nav list, with nested array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, properties, nav

I have two components that are loading some data. What I want is for the links to output like this:

- group1
  linka  linkb

But it's doing this

- group1
  linka
- group1
  linkb

I can understand it is to do with the use of my maps and how i am returning the data but I cant figure out how to fix it and keep the click handler working for the groups.

```
const navList = [
  {
    "GroupName": "group1",
    "links": [
        {"name": "link0a","id": "434"},
        {"name": "link0b","id": "342"}
    ]
},
{
    "GroupName": "group2",
    "links": [
        {"name": "link1a","id": "345"},
        {"name": "link1b","id": "908"}
    ]
  }
]

class Nav extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openItem: null
    }

    this.toggleClick = this.toggleClick.bind(this);
  }

  toggleClick(item, index, event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (index === this.state.openItem) {
        this.setState({openItem: null})
    } else {
        this.setState({openItem: index})
    }
 }

 render() {
    return (

            <ul>
                {navList.map((section, i) => {
                    const links = section.links.map((item, index) => {
                        const isOpen = this.state && this.state.openItem === index

                        return <NavItem title={section.GroupName} children={item.name} onClick={this.toggleClick.bind(null, item, index)} open={isOpen} />
                    })

                    return links
                })}
            </ul>

    )
  }
}

class NavItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const toggleClass = this.props.open ? 'is-open' : ''
    return (
        <li>
            <h2 onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.title}</h2>
            <ul className={toggleClass}>
                <li>{this.props.children}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    )
  }
}

export default NavItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{this.props.title}` from `NavLink` and move it in your `render()` function that you posted above. Otherwise, every time you render a NavLink, the title would be shown. Don't forget to move your `onClick` handler also.

Here is a working example based on your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/n21Lspm3/1/

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but it breaks the click handler

Comment: that's right, you have to move the click handler also

Comment: can you post the complete code of your both components then? Preferably, create a jsfiddle and I can have a look

Comment: This is my jsfiddle it doesn't actually work because es6 though..not sure how to fix that https://jsfiddle.net/x9orvsax/2/

Comment: see, I've posted a working jsfiddle. Hope that helps.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks so much, I also noticed I had to make some changes to my handleClick function which i had missed!

Comment: happens to all of us, glad to help;-)

Comment: Damn, @leo I actually realized it's not quite right, because it duplicates the UL which isnt ideal. Currently investigating a workaround.

Comment: I edited the jsfiddle, check it out again - you have to move ul out of the component also and className applied on li.

Comment: Yes i can see that works, this is how I thought to resolve but it doesn't seem ideal as you then cant control the styles from the UL as a container you have to deal with each list item individually. I'll work with that though, i cant see an alternative.

Comment: well, to be honest I woudln't mess with classes at all - this is against react. 

See a more natural react solution: https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/sLks2yjg/, in particular this line: return isOpen ? <NavItem key={index} title={section.GroupName} children={item.name} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, item, i)} /> : ""

Comment: So basically adding/removing the items instead? That doesn't seem particulary good for accessibility. Why is that more of a react solution?

Comment: Why accessibility? You have everything in your state anyways and shouldn't  manipulate DOM directly.

Against react is that you pollute the DOM with hidden HTML - your app becomes slower. It really depends on what you're doing to be honest, but adding / removing is generally better than messing with classes (for me)

Comment: Fair point, I see where you are coming from! Thanks for all your help.